# Identify who instantiates a COM interface

Tags: windows, security, com

I have some COM interface which I'd like to secure against attacks. The idea is to only allow the interface to be instantiated by compiled .exe files on the local computer and to find out, who tries to instantiate the interface. I can then check the signature of the .exe file and compare it so some hashes on in a database or something like that.

Is it possible to find out which program/process/whatever tries to instantiate a COM interface?

Comment: No.  Use CoInitializeSecurity()

Comment: It wouldn't help.  The bad guy could always launch one of the "approved" executables, with the main thread suspended, and then inject his own code into the process.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in-process COM, then your COM DLL is loaded into the calling process and you can use GetCurrentProcessID function to find the ID of the current process. Then [enumerate processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the system to check which one is yours.